# How do I find the largest number in each position of three possibly different length lists and find the sum of them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three inputs. a1, a2, and a3.

For example, here is an input:

-1, -2, -3

-4 -5 -6 -8 -9

-10 -11

The output would be -23.

Because when comparing the first position of each list, you find that the largest number is -1. Then -2, -3, -8, and -9.

Here is what i have so far. It seems like the program is working perfectly fine with positive numbers, but when it comes to negative numbers, the output is incorrect. The example I gave above outputted a -3 instead of a -23. How do I fix this?

```
a1 = a1.split()
a2 = a2.split()
a3 = a3.split()

length_one = len(a1)
length_two = len(a2)
length_three = len(a3)
longest_length = max(length_one, length_two, length_three)

if length_one < longest_length:
    difference_one = longest_length - length_one
    for i in range (difference_one):
        a1.append('0')

if length_two < longest_length:
    difference_two = longest_length - length_two
    for i in range (difference_two):
        a2.append('0')
        
if length_three < longest_length:
    difference_three = longest_length - length_three
    for i in range (difference_three):
        a3.append('0')

for i in range (longest_length):
    a1[i] = int(a1[i])
for i in range (longest_length):
    a2[i] = int(a2[i])
for i in range (longest_length):
    a3[i] = int(a3[i])      
       
sumlist = []

for i in range (longest_length):
    biggest_number = max(a1[i], a2[i], a3[i])
    sumlist.append(biggest_number)
 
total = 0
for i in range (len(sumlist)):
    total = total + sumlist[i]

return total
```

Comment: FYI the last loop can be replaced with `total = sum(sumlist)`

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the tip!

Comment: Are you restricted from using built-in functions like `max()` and `sum()`? Because it seems like you're making things much harder for yourself by not using them.

Comment: @Barmar it seems so. I tried the tip you gave me and the program output just gives me a runtime error.

Comment: This wors for positive numbers because you're appending 0 to each list (and any positive number is `> 0`). Try appending `float('-inf')` (a value that represents negative infinity) instead of 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like to use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).  It is just like [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) but greedy instead of lazy.

Each iteration slices off one element from each of `a1`, `a2`, `a3` and stored as a tuple `tup`.  We then select the maximum value to append to `res`, and drop the remaining two.  We then sum at end.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
a1 = [-1, -2, -3]
a2 = [-4, -5, -6, -8, -9]
a3 = [-10, -11]

res = [max(tup) for tup in zip_longest(a1, a2, a3, fillvalue=float('-inf'))]

print(sum(res))
```

Output:

```
-23
```

Comment: thank you! will it work for positive numbers as well?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? positive numbers are higher than negative infinity.

Comment: This is better than the solution I was going to post, which uses the default `None` fill of `zip_longest`, and then filters them out them when calling `max()`

Comment: As long as you are looking for minimum use float('-inf') as fill values and if it is maximum use float('inf') as fill values.

Comment: If the difference between the input lengths are large and the number of inputs to compare are large, then lazy zip* with additional for loop would work better as it will have less comparisons. But for just 3 inputs this is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works for positive numbers because you're appending `0` to the shorter lists, and any positiven number will be greater than `0`.

If you want it to work for an arbitrary negative number, I'd suggest appending `float('-inf')` instead. This is a value that represents negative infinity, and basically any numerical variable `x`, no matter how negative, will evaluate `True` to `x > float('-inf')`

since you're casting to `int`, you would need to slightly modify your code so that it works for `float` instead:

```py
a1 = a1.split()
a2 = a2.split()
a3 = a3.split()

length_one = len(a1)
length_two = len(a2)
length_three = len(a3)
longest_length = max(length_one, length_two, length_three)

if length_one < longest_length:
    difference_one = longest_length - length_one
    for i in range (difference_one):
        a1.append(float('-inf'))

if length_two < longest_length:
    difference_two = longest_length - length_two
    for i in range (difference_two):
        a2.append(float('-inf'))
        
if length_three < longest_length:
    difference_three = longest_length - length_three
    for i in range (difference_three):
        a3.append(float('-inf'))

for i in range (longest_length):
    a1[i] = float(a1[i])
for i in range (longest_length):
    a2[i] = float(a2[i])
for i in range (longest_length):
    a3[i] = float(a3[i])      
       
sumlist = []

for i in range (longest_length):
    biggest_number = max(a1[i], a2[i], a3[i])
    sumlist.append(biggest_number)
 
total = 0
for i in range (len(sumlist)):
    total = total + sumlist[i]

return total
```

Comment: it says that i have an overflow error. it says that i cannot convert float infinity to an integer. any thoughts?

Comment: @LucyL was your code `int(float('-inf'))`?

Comment: To fix that, you would need to replace your casting from `int(a1[i])` to `float(a1[i])` at the bottom of your code. I edited my answer with a modified version of your code.